How to make clone of a third party website UI (Only the necessary elements)?
I have a js script hosted on a URL. My script places a widget View on a site where it is placed. Now for presentation purpose, site owners wants to see the demo with their site structure placed with my widget.
As they are not a technical persons, How do I simplify the process of the demo, so that they can see the demo with their site structure. I understand it is not possible to replicate their UI fully or it will not be time worthy to copy exact. What is best possible way to do this? Also I do not want to spend too much time on creating demos. Is there any free tools available for this purpose?
Thanks.

perhaps write a Web Extension that does what you need

But owners have to install that extension on their end also I have to configure where do I place my custom widget on that site. is there any way to create an webpage with their basic structure and paste my code? Then I will then just provide them the link?

I also tried downloading their site and used that in my custom html. But is most cases css and other functionalities are broken as expected.

my suggestion was made because you can't figure out how to get a usable "copy" of their website - since I (nor anyone but you) know what website you're trying to copy, and what widget you're trying to add to it, it's very difficult (lets call it impossible) to tell you how to copy enough of someone's website so you can demonstrate your widget
